# Restrict ruby routes based on database parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Users model that has an admin field. This is boolean. I only want to a User to create/modify/update a "Season" if the admin field is equal to true. How would I go about doing this in rails? Do i put this logic in the "Season" controller? Something to do with my routes config?

Answer (score 2):

You can use single table inheritance like create a table User and create 2 more model like

```
Admin < User
```

{
  default_scope { where(user_type: :college) }
  ....
}

and

```
Supplier < User
```

{
   default_scope { where(user_type: :supplier) }
   ....
}

Answer (score 1):

Put the logic in the `SeasonsController` in a `before_action`, that performs your desired error action unless they are an admin.

```
class SeasonsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :ensure_admin_user!, except: [:show, :index]

  ...

  private

  def ensure_admin_user!
    render_error unless current_user.admin?
  end

  def render_error
    # whatever
  end
end
```

[Action Controller Docs: filters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you add a `before_action` filter in your controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :check_permission!, only: [:create, :update]

  # Your create, update actions

  private
  def check_permission!
    render status: :forbidden unless current_user.admin?
  end
end
```

Comment: So i've used this code and put the before_action into my SeasonsController and the private method into my application controller however I am logged in with a test user who has admin set to 0 in the database and he is still able to see everything... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by saying "see everything"? The above code only makes normal users unable to call `create` and `update` actions in `SessionsController`. They can still see the session form in your view but when they press the button "create" or "update" in the form, they get a "Permission denied" message.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `before_action` callback to check whether the user's admin field is true or false.

```
class SeasonsController 
   before_action :check_admin_field, only: [:edit, :new]

   protected
   def check_admin_field
      return User.find(params[:user_id]).admin_field
      # if you're using devise gem then check current_user.admin_field 
      # or you can redirect to other path with a notice
   end
end
```

You can check this [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters)

If you are not passing the `user_id` parameter in your URL then you have to change the `routes.rb` like:

```
resources :users do
  resources :seasons
end
```

This will create your `new` season route url like: `root_url/users/1/seasons/new`

Comment: Wouldn't this tie a User to a season? I wan't only an admin user to create a season. non-admin users can still see the season. There will be classes (like school classes) associated with the season.

Comment: All users can see the seasons. But the callback will run only before the new and edit action. If you don't want the nested route then then you have check your session for the current_user or if there's devise you've used then `current_user` will fetch the current logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

put 'seasons/:user_id/:id' => 'home#update', :constraints => {user_id: User.where(admin: true).pluck(:id) }

post 'seasons/:user_id/:id' => 'home#create', :constraints => {user_id: User.where(admin: true).pluck(:id) }

resources :seasons, except: [:create, :update]

Change your route.rb file as per above.